# Advice needed replacing 45 year old spigot

Tags: plumbing, water

I have to replace an old spigot which leaks from the threads when hose is attached.

My question - is there any way of knowing how it is attached to its 1/2" copper supply tube.  Sweated or threaded connection
On the basement side the copper tube leading to it goes into  wood siding surrounded by caulk.  I have attached closeups of the spigot and it appears there are two nails securing it to the aluminum siding The sides of the spigot adjacent to the nails have a flat area which might be for a wrench.
I just want to make sure because that I dont break the copper tubing in the basement if  I attempt to rotate the spigot  off with a wrench.

Any help with this would be appreciated[image]

enter image description here

[image]

Comment: These old faucets are repairable, depending on exactly whats wrong.  I would view replacement as a final option.

Comment: If leaking at the threads a new washer on the hose will fix that or replacing the hose end if the fitting is shot, I agree with jphil1618 the faucet itself is repairable but the hose is probably the problem. Pipe dope or tape is not how a hose seals it is the rubber or nylon washer that makes the seal.

Comment: Could it be leaking around the stem and running down to the hose threads? If so, tighten the bonnet nut or, if that doesn't work, replace the packing (water must be shut off for latter). You have not shown a need to replace this spigot. Does it drip when shut off? Is it hard to turn? As other comment pointed out the hose seals with a rubber or plastic seal in the hose fitting. These can dry up or pop out. Unless you have a very large hose, get the plastic sealing washers with "ears" --they fit easy and seal well.

Comment: Removing mineral deposits in the grooves of the hose threads might make the hose thread on easier.  Use regular vinegar and a brush to remove them. If the threads are still a little "catchy", dry and then dab a small amount of plumber's grease on the threads and see if that helps.

Comment: my opinion, even if you knew it was threaded on, after 45 years  it is highly unlikely you will successfully unscrew it and install a new one and have it not leak. Plan on cutting pipes to get the old one out of the way.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, the fact that spigot has two flats in front of the flange (for a smooth jaw wrench such as a crescent wrench or monkey wrench (but not a pipe wrench (serrated jaws) which would squeeze the brass spigot, possibly deforming the threaded fitting on the pipe)) suggests it is has female threads.

It is likely that there is some play in the pipes.  Remove the two nails and it might pull out 1/2", affording a view behind the flange.

However, even if it is threaded at the spigot, its risky putting a wrench only on the spigot.  Those threads might be very tight, whereas a sweated connection some where under the house could be weak.  Thus two wrenches are required, one on the spigot and one on the pipe side.

Alternatively, you could buy a small adapter to mount onto the spigot long-term with plumbers paste or teflon tape or whatever stops the leak, then attach the hose when needed to the spigot.  For example, one kind of adapter would be a quick-connect. Another type would be a splitter. Another type would be a swivel union. Another type would be an antisiphon coupler.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like he has a few threads that have flattened out. Yes try a washer first, however, you would have no way of knowing how it is attached if you said you follow the pipe out the spigot and don't see anything. I would hazard a guess it was sweat on, then pushed into the siding, and sweat at the main line connection end. If you replace it, you would need to cut the pipe and pull it out. Then sweat a new piece on or use a shark-bite connector. Then the spigot end can be replaced however you like.